# Calling a prototype function on an object's data while minimizing memory usage

Tags: javascript, performance

Learning Javascript; I want to reduce memory usage by using a prototype function (#2). However, in order to pass relevant state/arguments from an instance to the prototype function, I need to create another function (#1).

I understand that in Javascript, the object method (#1) would be created for each Row instance, negating memory savings from re-using the prototype function (#2). Memory savings would also be negated if I replaced function #1 with a closure.

Is there a way for each Row object to call the prototype function on the Row's own unique state while still minimizing memory usage?

```
function Row(data) { 
  row = Object.create(Row.prototype);
  row.state = data;

  //#1
  row.showInstanceState = function() {
    Row.prototype.showState(this.state);
  };

  return row; 
}

//#2
Row.prototype.showState = function(info) {
    console.log(info);
}

let example = new Row(2);

/*
If function #1 didn't exist, the call 
below saves memory but we have explicitly pass 
in an instance's data at the moment of the call. 
*/
example.showState(example.state);

//The call style below is desired, but requires function #1, which would not optimize memory usage.
example.showInstanceState();
```

Comment: I'm not understanding something, why can't you just put `showInstanceState` on the prototype?

Comment: I'm not understanding why you would use `prototype` at all, in a case where you have access to just add to the constructor. By the way, JavaScript constructors return `this` by default. Ridiculous design.

Comment: Your use of prototypes and constructors is totally off. How did your code look without them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `new` keyword, you're basically running your `Row()` function with `this` pointing to a newly (and automatically) created object and returning that object. So your function constructor should look like this:

```js
function Row(data) { 
  this.state = data;
}
```

The object and its prototype will already be assigned when using `new`.

Then you can add your prototype methods:

```js
Row.prototype.showInstanceState = function() {
  console.log(this.state);
};
```

When you call methods as members of an instance, `this` will always point to the instance object (unless you're using `call` or `apply`), so `this.state` will point to the instance own property (which you created in the constructor).

```js
let example = new Row(2);
let example2 = new Row(5);

example.showInstanceState(); // 2
example2.showInstanceState(); // 5
```

Comment: I'll try to come up a better (but likely still contrived) example that better reflects a nuanced situation I'm dealing with. I also lack the proper terminology to describe my issue. My head should be clearer tomorrow after I get some sleep.